# Having the upper bound of a foreach loop be an index from an array

Tags: pgffor

Say i have two nested foreach loops.

```
\foreach \i in {0, ..., 3}
{
    \foreach[parse=true] \j in {0, ..., {1, 5, 7, 8}[\i]}
    {
    }
}
```

This results in an extra '}' error. How could i achieve this?

My intention is to be able to draw a 2d grid of circles. But with the length of each row being able to vary in a preset pattern, I.E with values specified in a list. Something like this.

```
 ooooo
  ooo
ooooooo
  ooo
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What is your intended result?

Comment: Do you maybe just mean `\foreach \i in {1,5,7,8}` (with only one loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parse` options of PGFFor is a bit finicky, especially if the last item comes directly after `...`. It usally helps to add `0+` in front of it (sometimes just `+` is enough but not in this case).

I've added another double-loop construct that doesn't use an array but instead uses the list `1, 5, 7, 8` directly as the entries of the outer loop. Counting up from `0` is still possible by using the `count` option of PGFFor.

Don't forget that if the list is stored in a macro you can use that macro directly as the list:

```
\newcommand*\myList{1, 5, 7, 8}
\foreach \i in \myList {
  …
}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
Loops:
\foreach \i in {0, ..., 3}{
  \par $ i = \i $:%
  \foreach[parse=true] \j in {0, ..., 0+{1, 5, 7, 8}[\i]}{
    $j = \j$,%
  }
}
\vspace{1em}
\foreach[count=\cnt from 0] \i in {1, 5, 7, 8}{
  \par \cnt. item: $ i = \i $:%
  \foreach \j in {0, ..., \i}{
    $j = \j$,%
  }
}
\end{document}
```

#### Bonus

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz[y=-1cm, radius=.4]\draw 
  foreach[count=\y from 0] \i in {1, 5, 7, 8}{
    [shift=(left:{(\i-1)/2})]
    foreach \x in {0, ..., \i}{
      (\x, \y) circle[] } };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]